# how color odd even with angular5

Tags: angular, less, ngfor

I, this is my template for hours in calendar:

```html
<ul class="heure" *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche; let even = even; let odd = odd" [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even } ">
    <li >{{ heure }} H</li>
</ul>
```

i would like applicate this css in less:

```css
.heure{
    li{
        float: left;
        width:2.5em;
    }
}
.even { background-color: red; }
.odd { background-color: green; }
```

my result is:

```html
Lun
  
10 H
11 H
12 H
13 H
14 H
15 H
```

I would show the hours add and event for more visibility
my component is here:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heure',
  templateUrl: './heure.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heure.component.css']
})
export class HeureComponent implements OnInit {

  trancheDeb = 0;
  trancheFin = 24;
  libelleTranche=new Array(); //calculé fin de tranche - debut de tranche
  constructor() { 
    let plageJour = this.trancheFin - this.trancheDeb;

    for(let i=0;i<plageJour;i++){
      this.libelleTranche.push(i);
    }

    console.log(this.libelleTranche);
  }

}
```

how i must do for color correctly odd and event hours ?
thank for reply :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`even` and `odd` variable provide by `ngFor` directive is based on currentElement `index`. For your case you should set `odd` & `even` value based on `(heure % 2)` calculation result.

```
<ul class="heure" 
  *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche" 
  [ngClass]="{ odd: (heure%2 == 0), even: heure %2 == 1 } ">
    <li >{{ heure }} H</li>
</ul>
```

[Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9edjrk)

Answer (score 2):

```html
<ul class="heure" *ngFor="let heure of libelleTranche; let even = even; let odd = odd" >
    <li [ngClass]="{ odd: odd, even: even } ">{{ heure }} H</li>
</ul>
```